# Ubuntu 22.04 suspend without password

Tags: login, suspend, 22.04, password

So I just upgraded to 22.04, Until now after 15-30 minutes the screen locked and I needed a password to login again. Now its not happening an I can figure out what changed?
[image]

Thanks,

Raz

Answer (score 0):

Update on misread, to enable automatic screen lock:

Settings > Privacy > **Automatic Screen Lock**: [enable automatic screen lock - ubuntu 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ95u.png)

From settings go to Privacy > Screen > **Lock Screen on Suspend** : (disable it) enabled by default.
[Disable Lock screen on suspend from settings > privacy > screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuA8N.png)

Comment: I have it off (`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend` outputs `false`) but screen unlock still requires password.